# C# desktop app/SQL Server backup strategies

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup-strategies

I am planning to make a C# desktop app with SQL Server 2019 Express.
Because I am not so familiar with SQL Sever, it'd be appreciated if any advice given on the feasibility of my thoughts, thanks in advance!

#### Here are my planned backup strategies:

- This app is for personal use, I make it and I use it.
- Any modification to the database will be wrapped as a transaction.
- Full backup of the target database will be conducted once a day, and differential backup **EVERY TIME** after successfully committed a transaction.
- All backups are using BACKUP statement through C# code.

#### Questions:

1. Because I have backup for every modification, so I can just use "Simple" restore model, and there is no need to use Transaction Log backup, is that right?
2. For the same reason, I don't need to backup every time I close the app, right?
   Why I am asking this is because differential backup take about 560KB even right after a full backup and without any change.
3. Do I need to backup system databases other than the one used by the app?
   (I might change hosting pc in the future, can the backups be restored to other SQL Server instances without system databases backups?)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to take some sort of backup after every transaction?  That is highly unusual.

Comment: Because my database would be relatively small and there could be only a few transactions a day say 10~20, and I don't want to lose any data. Plus some times I might need to roll back certain transactions, like a time machine?

Comment: Then  you should use FULL recovery and backup the log periodically.

Comment: Thanks, what’s the difference? File size?

Comment: A differential contains all the changes since the last FULL, and so is excessive.  And if you have log backups you can restore to any point-in-time.

Comment: I thought log is a little difficult to learn so tried to avoid it, maybe I should spend some time on it. Besides, do I need to back up system databases?